# JBoss7.1 final 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: jboss, jaxb

I'm trying to migrate app from jboss 5.1 to 7.1 and i have error like this [Error message](http://pastie.org/5488987) which i'm not sure why i get this. if anyone have any idea please help me.

Update: 1

```
@Stateless
@Remote(PackageService.class)
@Interceptors(CrossContextSpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@WebContext(contextRoot="/appname_web_services", urlPattern="/MaintenanceService", authMethod="", secureWSDLAccess=false)
@WebService(
   name="MaintenanceService",
   targetNamespace = "http://appname.com/web/services",
   serviceName = "MaintenanceService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED) 
@HandlerChain(file = "WebServiceHandlerChains.xml")
@TransactionTimeout(10800)
public class MaintenanceServiceBean implements MaintenanceService {

    private static final Logger logger =  Logger.getLogger( MaintenanceServiceBean.class );

    @Resource(mappedName="/ConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName="topic/manager_system_topic")
    javax.jms.Destination systemTopic;

    @Autowired
    MaintenanceService MigrationService;

    @WebMethod
    public List<Long> getSoftDeletedPackageIds(Long performedBy) throws Exception {
        return MigrationService.getSoftDeletedPackageIds(null);
    }
```

this is the class where i believe it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an interface in your JAXB mappings for which you have not provided enough information to the runtime for it too be able to bind an actual implementation. Without more code included in your question it's hard to recommend a specific solution, but typically you would annotate the included interface with @XmlAnyElement.

You can read through [this useful tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html) to determine the best solution for your possible case.

Comment: Well where exactly i have to set that annotation because the app what i'm trying to migrate is not written by me but i can provide some code examples if you want for specific classes if you can see from the error log which classes you will need.

Comment: i have added the class where is fails.